# ArrayList OutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, exception, arraylist

I'm using an `ArrayList` to create a list of fish that I will need to manage in my program.
The issue I am having is that when filling the list with the number of fishes entered, I'm getting an exception and the program crashes.

Here's my code:

```
Random RandomGenerator = new Random();

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

int simulation = 0;

System.out.println("Veuillez entrer le nombre de poissons carnivores:");
nbre_c = sc.nextInt();
System.out.println("Veuillez entrer le nombre de poissons herbivores:");
nbre_h = sc.nextInt();
System.out.println("Veuillez entrer le nombre d'algues:");
nbre_a = sc.nextInt();

sc.close();


ArrayList<Herbivor> list_h = new ArrayList<Herbivor>();
ArrayList<Carnivor> list_c = new ArrayList<Carnivor>();
ArrayList<Algue> list_a = new ArrayList<Algue>();

while(simulation<100)
{
    System.out.println("Début de la simulation: ");
    int nb = nbre_c;
    for(int i = 0; i<nb;i++) // Issue #`1` 
    {
        Carnivor c = new Carnivor();
        list_c.add(c);
    }

    nb = nbre_h;
    for(int i = 0; i<nb;i++) // Creation des Poissons Herbivores
    {
        Herbivor h = new Herbivor();
        list_h.add(h);
    }

    nb = nbre_a;
    for(int i = 0; i<nb;i++) // Creation des Algues
    {
        Algue a = new Algue();
        list_a.add(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the (full) text of the exception?  What line does it reference? What input are you giving your program? It's very difficult to answer a question based on incomplete information.

Comment: This should work. Is the exception happening in code you haven't posted?

Comment: Yep sorry, here's the console output:  

`
Veuillez entrer le nombre de poissons carnivores:  
10  
Veuillez entrer le nombre de poissons herbivores:  
10  
Veuillez entrer le nombre d'algues:  
5  
Début de la simulation:   
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:   Index: 16, Size: 10
 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635)  
 at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)  
 at Ocean.main(Ocean.java:128)`

Comment: Then go to line 128 of your Ocean class. You probably didn't check list.size() in a loop, or you checked the size() of the wrong list. Copy pasted a for loop perhaps?

Comment: Please, ***please*** don't paste large blocks of text into a comment.  If you want to add more information to your question, *edit your question and add it*.

Comment: Thanks @RoelStrolenberg, now it's working. Sorry azurefrog for the mess, next time i'll edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

Two tips:

1- The variable RandomGenerator not used in the code.(but not important)

2- The value of simulation set to zero that causes infinite loop.(very important)

I think attention to the Second tip causes solve your problem.